# Typescript, tests and debugging in VS Code

Tags: angular, debugging, testing, visual-studio-code, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular2 and typescript and have made a simple application which was generated with the angular CLI. Before I go on, I have to say that there is a gap in my understanding of what happens between seeing typescript code in VS Code and a running app in the browser.

In previous editors, I was used to seeing .js files generated and made sense of my running application as a web page with those generated files. But when one runs `ng serve` there are no .js files anywhere and the app still runs in the browser. The first thing I want to know is how that happens- I thought typescript was not readable by browsers.

Secondly, I am having trouble debugging unit tests in the Karma test runner using VS Code. I am able to debug the application itself, I am able to attach the debugger to the Karma instance, but when I put a breakpoint in my test I get the error `breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)`. For reference this is my `launch.json`:

```
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach Karma Chrome",
        "address": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 9333,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
```

and my `karma.conf.js` contains

```
browsers: ['ChromeDebugging'],
customLaunchers : {
  ChromeDebugging: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: ['--remote-debugging-port=9333']
  }
},
```

EDIT: This is the full [karma.conf.js](https://pastebin.com/REmkMVKG)

Comment: Your configuration works well for me. Can you provide full `karma.conf.js` contents?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach Karma Chrome",
        "address": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 9333,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/test"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to debug tests in the browser using the [angular seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) repository